# disable/enable text boxes by using wicket

Tags: java, wicket

my requirement is based on group of checkbox checks shipping address fields will be disable or enabled.

make clear my requirement:Wicket id:"nonDigital" having 6 check boxes.if any one of check box is checked then only shipping address section is enabled and then only user can enter value.

Here is my code

My HTML code:

```
 <fieldset class="deliveryFormats">
          <h2 class="sectionHeading">Delivery Formats</h2>
          <span class="required">* Required Field</span>
         <br/>
            <div class="leftDiv">
          <label>Non-digital</label>
          <div class="radioLabel" wicket:id="nonDigital" >
            <label>
             <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="formatType" />Beta SP NTSC
            </label>
           </div><!--  /.radioLabel non digital -->
</fieldset>
<fieldset class="shippingAddress" style="border-bottom: 0px;" >
           <h2 class="sectionHeading">Shipping Address</h2>
          <table class="form">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <th class="fieldName" scope="row">Company</th>
                <td class="fieldEdit">
                  <input class="organization" type="text" wicket:id="address.organization"/>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th class="fieldName" scope="row">Address 1</th>
                <td class="fieldEdit">
                  <input class="long" type="text" wicket:id="address.line1">
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th class="fieldName" scope="row">Address 2</th>
                <td class="fieldEdit">
                  <input class=" long" type="text" wicket:id="address.line2">
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th class="fieldName" scope="row">Address 3</th>
                <td class="fieldEdit">
                  <input class="long" type="text" wicket:id="address.line3">
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th class="fieldName" scope="row">City</th>
                <td class="fieldEdit">
                  <input class="long" type="text" wicket:id="address.city"/>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th class="fieldName" scope="row">State</th>
                <td class="fieldEdit">
                  <input class="long" type="text" wicket:id="address.state"/>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th class="fieldName" scope="row">Postal Code</th>
                <td class="fieldEdit">
                  <input class="postalcode" type="text" wicket:id="address.postalCode"/>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
```

Java code:

```
List<DeliveryFormat> formatChoices = lookupProcessor.getLookupValues(DeliveryFormat.class);
List<DeliveryFormat> nonDigital = new ArrayList<DeliveryFormat>();
List<DeliveryFormat> digital = new ArrayList<DeliveryFormat>();

            Iterator<DeliveryFormat> nondigitalIterator = formatChoices.iterator();
            while(nondigitalIterator.hasNext()){
                DeliveryFormat df = nondigitalIterator.next();
                if(df.getLabel().equals("Audio Bundle") || df.getLabel().equals("XDCAM file")|| df.getLabel().equals("FTP")){
                    digital.add(df);
                }
                else
                {
                    nonDigital.add(df);
                }
            }

         //Add the check boxes for Delivery format for digital List

          // add(new CheckBoxMultipleChoice<DeliveryFormat>("nonDigital", nonDigital, new ChoiceRenderer<DeliveryFormat>("label")));
         ChoiceRenderer<DeliveryFormat> deliveryFormatShippment = new ChoiceRenderer<DeliveryFormat>("label", "id");
            CheckBoxMultipleChoice<DeliveryFormat> nonDigitalDelivery = new CheckBoxMultipleChoice<DeliveryFormat>(
                    "nonDigital", nonDigital, deliveryFormatShippment);

            CheckBoxMultipleChoice<DeliveryFormat> digitalDelivery = new CheckBoxMultipleChoice<DeliveryFormat>(
                    "digital", digital, deliveryFormatShippment);
            add(nonDigitalDelivery);
 /*final CheckBox test = new CheckBox("nonDigital");
            test.setOutputMarkupId(true);

            nonDigitalDelivery.add(new AjaxEventBehavior("onKeyUp")
            {

                *//**
                 * 
                 *//*
                private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

                @Override
                protected void onEvent(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    test.setEnabled(false);
                    target.addComponent(test);
                }

            });*/
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try to enable the markupid to be written:

```
textArea.setOutputMarkupId(true);
```

and then add this component to the target:

```
textArea.setEnabled(false):
target.add(textArea);
```

Comment: address.ogranization is my text area and nonDigitalDelivery is my check box list

Comment: Hi thg,This is my checkbox group:CheckBoxMultipleChoice<DeliveryFormat> nonDigitalDelivery = new CheckBoxMultipleChoice<DeliveryFormat>(
                    "nonDigital", nonDigital, deliveryFormatShippment);Here nondigital is my Wicket id

Comment: i will give more clarification:i have checkbox group will display 6 check boxes.if i click on any check box corresponding text area"like address.orginization(wicket id)" will enabled.bydefault in page loading if check box is not checked the text area would be disabled

Comment: Yeah from your code i could not see much but remember the following: you have to add the component to be changed not the changing component to the target.

Comment: Will add wicket id for fieldset or table?

Comment: if every component you use in the code has a wicket:id you should be fine but you need to setoutputmarkupid to true for a component you want changed via ajax. you should also add the component you want changed to the target not the component that is causing the change. I edited my post to show my suggestion